# Agregar un input para escribir el barcode de un producto, me muestre la descripción del producto en otro input, con un btn agregarlo a una tabla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

[![Tengo esto en el Controller[image: Tengo esta funcionY esta en que dependiendo la sucursal se muestra en un select una lista de productos, pero yo quuero que dependiendo en un input (codigoBarras) me muestre en el que era un select, solo la descripcion del producto]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Cuál input, cuál botón, cuál tabla? Lo otro, todo va como texto así como nadie te va a poner a transcribir código desde imágenes. Código, mensajes de error, todo va como texto. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).